# Search file in other google drives

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a google drive where am storing few google sheets. My java web application is able to search a file that is present in my own google drive using Javascript API. Is there a way to search for a specific files in other's google drive via code? i will be getting the shareable link to the google drive am supposed to search. can this be done? As far as i checked this is not possible. Also there is no where in google document that says i can search files in other's drive. Kindly someone confirm.

Comment: Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#AboutAuthorization

Comment: Yes. Am already doing the OAuth and having scope to read the data. Am able to search specific files from my own drive. Am not getting anywhere in reading files from other's drive. For ex, if you provide me a shareable link to your drive, how can i search and read files from your drive?

Answer (score 1):

This is an OAuth question, not a GDrive question.

The account that the GDrive API will apply to is determined by the Access Token that it is called with. So, if you can get an Access Token for somebody else's Drive, then you can use that to search their drive. How you would get such a token will depend very much on the details of your use case and the trust relationship.

Comment: Am using Javascript API to search the google drive. Am only giving the Client ID of the google account. So i changed the client id to other client ID. Still not able to fetch other records.. Any documentation available on this you can point me to?

Comment: it seems like you have a lot of research to do. "Client ID of the google account" is fundamentally wrong. The "Client" is your application, not the account. Getting an Access Token for a given account requires either that the account owner is present (ie. logged in), or has granted you offline access and you have saved a Refresh Token.

Comment: I suspect that is not possible. But you really think its possible to achieve this?

Comment: It's very, very easy, it just requires the Account holder to grant permission to your app. In dong that, your app will receive either an Access Token, or a  Refresh Token that can be used to request an Access Token. Armed with an Access Token, your app can do whatever the account holder permitted it to do. Again, you really need to understand that GDrive has no concept of "my account" vs "his account". It simply access whatever account the Access Token is associated with.

Comment: So there is no fixed user who will do this always. Also this has to be a complete backend process where front end is not at all involved. Still it is possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. There will need to be a one off front end interaction for each user to authorise your app to access his drive.